# Interpolate python lists at different rates to get equally spaced values

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation, distance

I have two lists in Python, which correspond to the x-coordinates and the y-coordinates in a 2d array while circling around an ellipse. The x-coordinates look something like this: `x_coords = [299.97, 298, 297, 296, 295.41, 295, 294.91, 295.012, 295.58, 296.1, ...]`, and `y_coords` is the same length but has different values.

As you can see, the values are not equally spaced, and they increase and decrease throughout the list (as they are going around the ellipse). I can compute the distance between any two adjacent (x,y) points on the ellipse with:

```
import numpy as np
distances = []
for i in range(len(x_coords)):
    if i==len(x_coords)-1:
        break
    dist = np.sqrt((x_coords[i+1]-x_coords[i])**2 + (y_coords[i+1]-y_coords[i])**2)
    distances.append(dist)
```

When I print `distances`, I can see that they are all different. So my (x, y) coordinate pairs are not equally spaced. I would like to find a way to make them all equally spaced. I imagine this would involve interpolating in between each value within `x_coords` and `y_coords` such that `distances` returns values that are all equal. Of course, `x_coords` and `y_coords` also need to still have equal lengths so that `(x_coords[i], y_coords[i])` will correspond to an (x, y) point at the same position in space. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can these values be created from scratch using a formula for an ellipse, or are the only available inputs `x_coords` and `y_coords` which have to be 'fixed'?

Comment: Seems to me like the better idea is to fit an ellipse and then sample from that function.

Comment: The initial `x_coords` and `y_coords` values are fixed (I got them from a contour in an image).

Comment: Are you using OpenCV? You can use [`cv2.fitEllipse()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#fitellipse) to get an ellipse from a contour. Or if you're using scikit-image, you can use [`skimage.measure.EllipseModel()`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.13.x/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.EllipseModel).

Comment: I am not -- I generated the contour within ds9. Can I somehow use OpenCV to feed in my x and y coords to then generate an ellipse?

Comment: I linked to documentation for both OpenCV and scikit-image to fit ellipses to that comment. They both take in a sequence of points and fit an ellipse to those points with a linear least squares model, and both libs are compatible with numpy. You can also just use plain ol' scipy with [`scipy.optimize.least_squares()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) and defining the ellipse function for fitting, but would take more tweaking. The others are well built-out for ellipses specifically already.

Comment: Presumably you know the size of the major and minor axis of your ellipse. To make evenly spaced points you should calculate the perimeter of the ellipse (using perhaps one of Ramanujan's approximations). Then divide perimeter by n to get the point spacing. You already know some points (one the major and minor axes). To fill in the rest of the points, in two nested loops, vary x and y by very small amounts. And when the distance from last_point is about at the spacing you want (within 1%?), append to your list and set last_point to current_point. You can use symmetry and solve for one quadrant.